# How to compare two DataTable with different number of columns?

Tags: c#, datatable

If I want to compare two datatables and get the difference in new datatable but I want to keep an uncompared column. 
example:

first Datatable

```
Name | Number
---- |-------
Jude | 12
Mark | 14
Bin  | 15
```

second Datatable

```
Name
------
Jude
Robin
Kamil
```

the Datatable must have:

```
Name   | Number
-------|----------
Mark   | 14
Bin    | 15
```

I have this method which can compare the two datatables and get the difference, but how can I get the number.

```
public static DataTable CompareTables(DataTable first, DataTable second)
{
first.TableName = "FirstTable";
second.TableName = "SecondTable";

//Create Empty Table
DataTable table = new DataTable("Difference");

try
{
//Must use a Dataset to make use of a DataRelation object
using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
{
//Add tables
ds.Tables.AddRange(new DataTable[] { first.Copy(), second.Copy() });

//Get Columns for DataRelation
DataColumn[] firstcolumns = new DataColumn[1];
firstcolumns[0] = ds.Tables[0].Columns[0];

DataColumn[] secondcolumns = new DataColumn[1];
secondcolumns[0] = ds.Tables[1].Columns[0];

//Create DataRelation
DataRelation r = new DataRelation(string.Empty, firstcolumns, secondcolumns, false);

ds.Relations.Add(r);

//Create columns for return table
for (int i = 0; i < first.Columns.Count; i++)
{
table.Columns.Add(first.Columns[i].ColumnName, first.Columns[i].DataType);
}

//If First Row not in Second, Add to return table.
table.BeginLoadData();

foreach (DataRow parentrow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
DataRow[] childrows = parentrow.GetChildRows(r);
if (childrows == null || childrows.Length == 0)
table.LoadDataRow(parentrow.ItemArray, true);
}

table.EndLoadData();

}
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}

return table;
}
```

Comment: Please provide more details on 1) On what base you are finding difference - different columns or difference between data. 2)What do you mean by 'I want to keep an uncompared column'? So, do you want Union or Intersection of two tables and on what criteria?

Comment: difference between data, as I show in the example above, Mark and Bin are the difference because they are not exist id the second table.

Comment: So you want table Three from First table based on comparison between First table and Second table where Name is present in First table but not in Second table. As in your case you eliminated Jude which is present in both tables hence output is Mark and Bin numbers. If my understanding is correct and which is based on data then why can't you handle it while fetching data?

Answer (score 0):

Let the database handle these things:

```
SELECT name, number from table1 where name not in (select name from table2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static DataTable CompareTables(DataTable first, DataTable second)
    {
        second.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] {second.Columns["Name"]};

        DataTable difference = second.Clone();

        foreach (DataRow row in first.Rows) {
            if (second.Rows.Find(row["Name"]) == null)
            {
                difference.ImportRow(row);
            }
        }

        return difference;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@user3527065 your code will throw an argument exception as the no. of columns has to be same .
DataRelation r = new DataRelation(string.Empty, firstcolumns, secondcolumns, false);
I your case firstcolumns has 2 columns whereas second columns has 1 column so it would throw an argument exception.

Comment: But how does this answer the question?